# uncaught error java.net.sockettimeoutexception failed to connect to/192.168.25.167 (port 19000) from /192.168.25.58 (port 49558) after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo, expo-go

uncaught error java.net.sockettimeoutexception failed to connect to/192.168.25.167 (port 19000) from /192.168.25.58 (port 49558) after 10000ms

i have change ip address also by
set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME='ipv4 address'
but still not working

Comment: sounds like that port isnt open on your OS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error message pretty much explains it,  the machine `192.168.25.167` on port `19000` cannot be connected to via the machine @ `192.168.25.58`, likely firewall settings, or could even be router based, unfortunately this is something you will need to  track down, as different OS's / or Hardware can vary dramatically.